# How to get the value of the select tag without action in my form?

Tags: php, html

I have a code that displays a dropdown with values 1-10. What I want to do is to get the value of the dropdown without using action in my form. I have the following code.

```
<form method="post" action="addtocart.php" class="frmProd">
    <h2>QUANTITY</h2>
            <?php
                if (isset($_GET['id']))
                {

                include('db.php');

                $id=$_GET['id'];
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = $id");

                echo'
                <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="'.$id.'">
                <table border="1" width="95%">'; 

                echo'<tr><td colspan="3" align="center">
                        <select name="selectQty" id="selectQty">
                            <option name="qty" value="1">1</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="2">2</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="3">3</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="4">4</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="5">5</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="6">6</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="7">7</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="8">8</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="9">9</option>
                            <option name="qty" value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                    </td></tr>';

                  echo'<tr>
                    <th>TYPE</th>
                    <th>PRICE</th>
                    <th width="100px">ACTIONS</th>';

                    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {

                      echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td align="center"><label name="pack" value="Pack">Pack</label></td>';
                        echo '<td align="center">'.$row3['Price'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td align="center">'.'<a href="addtocart.php?Id='.$row3['ID'].'&QTY='.$_POST['selectQty'].'"><input type="button" name="buyPack" value="Buy"></a>'.'</td>';
                      echo '</tr>';

                      echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td align="center">Box</td>';
                        echo '<td align="center">'.$row3['PriceBox'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td align="center">'.'<a href="addtocartbox.php?Id='.$row3['ID'].'&QTY='.$_POST['selectQty'].'"><input type="button" name="buyBox" value="Buy"></a>'.'</td>';
                      echo '</tr>';

                    }
                }
                    echo'</table>';
            ?>
</form>
```

In my code, I put the value of the dropdown using $_POST['selectQty'] in my a href in each button (I used GET to retrieve the values) but it doesn't have a value. I also tried putting it in a variable before passing but no luck. I debugged by putting an exact value (2 specifically) in the QTY in my button and it passed the value. Is there something wrong with how I am retrieving the value of my dropdown?

Thanks for the replies. :)

Comment: Only when you submit the form you will have values in the $_GET/$_POST. the other way you can achieve this is on change of the select box write a jQuery function and get the selected value ... pass this selected value to the ahref you are referring

Comment: How can I pass the value after I get it using JS?

Comment: you can alter the HTML using jQuery.. try adding an id to each anchor element.. based on this id modify it's value using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/
Which is basically doing `$('.selectQty').val()`